# android shell mkdir out of memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory, mkdir

I use adb shell to access an Android 4.4.2 tablet through a USB connection.
When trying to create a folder in the internal storage (/storage/sdcard0) I get the error 'Out of memory'. 
The device has 20+ GB of free space and also has a second sd card mounted as /storage/sdcard1 where the folder can be created just fine.
Both volumes are using msdos.
I tried fsck_msdos to /dev/block/vold/179:9 (the physical path) but found no errors. 
Any ideas before factory resetting the thing?

Comment: Your sdcard0 might not have been mounted correctly. Maybe use 

    `remount /storage/sdcard0`

and try it again?

Comment: This was really weird! I did a mount -o remount /storage/sdcard0 and worked as you suggested! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What suggested by Saehun was the correct answer but because I can't give the credits to him I close my own question. Thanks again Saehun!